# jq create output in many separate files

Tags: json, file, group-by, jq

given the following json:

```
    [
    {"_id":{"$oid":"6d2"},"jlo":"ΕΙ AJSB","dd":"d5f"},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"c6d3"},"jlo":"ΕΙ ALKSB","dd":"5d9"},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"b0cc6d4"},"jlo":"ΕΙ AGHTSB","dd":"1b1"},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"6d2"},"jlo":"ΕPOWΙ AJSB","dd":"d5f"},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"c6d3"},"jlo":"ΕGTΙ ALKSB","dd":"5d9"},
    {"_id":{"$oid":"b0cc6d4"},"jlo":"ΕLKΙ AGHTSB","dd":"1b1"}
    ]
```

what i need to do is have as output for each discrete value of the ll element, the unique values of ta, in a separate file, named after a one to one representation where each dd code is substituted with a human readable representation:

```
d5f:departmentone
5d9:departmentalt
1b1:departshort
```

Desired output, in a per row basis, each unique value of jlo with the count of times it was found in each dd element so we get in the end something like this:

```
first file named departmentone.txt:
ΕΙ AJSB 1
ΕPOWΙ AJSB 1

second file named departmentalt.txt
ΕΙ ALKSB 1
ΕGTΙ ALKSB 1

third file named departshort.txt
ΕΙ AGHTSB 2
```

i have tried with map and reduce, group_by, sort_by, with really poor results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one invocation of jq is necessary.  To allocate the output to the separate files, you can combine this one invocation with a single invocation to awk, or you could use a shell loop as illustrated below.

First, here's an illustration of how the shell pipeline would look:

```
jq -r --rawfile dd2name dd2name.tsv -f group.jq input.json |
  while IFS=$'\t' read -r f v ; do echo "$v" >> "$f" ; done
```

This assumes that the mapping to filenames is in a TSV file named dd2name.tsv, and that the following jq program is in group.jq:

```
def dict:
  split("\n") | map(select(length>0) | split("\t"))
  | INDEX(.[0]) | map_values(.[1]);

($dd2name | dict) as $dict
| ($dict | keys_unsorted[]) as $dd
| map(select(.dd == $dd))
| group_by(.jlo)
| map("\($dict[$dd])\t\(.[0].jlo) \(length)")[]
```

As the name suggests, the `dict` function creates a dictionary giving the mapping of .dd values to the filenames.  It assumes the availability of `INDEX`.  If your jq does not have `INDEX`, then now would be an excellent time to upgrade your jq; otherwise, its def can easily be copied from builtin.jq (google: `builtin.jq "def INDEX"`), or you could replace the last line by: `| reduce .[] as $p ({}; .[$p[0]] = $p[1]);`

### awk-based solution

The following invocation of awk can be used instead of the `while ... done` command above:

```
awk -F\\t 'fn && (fn!=$1) {close(fn)}; {fn=$1; print $2 >> fn}'
```

### Season to taste

If the dd2name.tsv mapping file does not contain the ".txt" suffix, it can easily be added in any of a variety of ways, according to taste.

Note also that the proposed solutions above make some assumptions, notably that the .jlo values do not contain tabs, newlines, or NULs.  If any of those assumptions is violated, then some tweaking will be required.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in three passes, filtering the array with the desired `dd` and grouping by `jlo`, then extracting the `jlo` of the first (guaranteed) item of the array and its length :

```
map(select(.dd == "d5f")) | group_by(.jlo) | map("\(.[0].jlo) \(length)") | .[]
```

You can [try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/bffxEaU4Rf).

Full bash run :

```
jq --arg dd d5f --raw-output 'map(select(.dd == $dd)) | group_by(.jlo) | map("\(.[0].jlo) \(length)") | .[]' yourJsonFile > departmentone.txt
jq --arg dd 5d9 --raw-output 'map(select(.dd == $dd)) | group_by(.jlo) | map("\(.[0].jlo) \(length)") | .[]' yourJsonFile > departmentalt.txt
jq --arg dd 1b1 --raw-output 'map(select(.dd == $dd)) | group_by(.jlo) | map("\(.[0].jlo) \(length)") | .[]' yourJsonFile > departmentshort.txt
```

Supposing you have a file named "mapping.txt" with the following content :

```
d5f:departmentone
5d9:departmentalt
1b1:departshort
```

You could extract those codes and labels to generate the files :

```
while IFS=: read -r code label; do
    jq --arg dd $code --raw-output 'map(select(.dd == $dd)) | group_by(.jlo) | map("\(.[0].jlo) \(length)") | .[]' yourJsonFile > "$label".txt
done < mapping.txt
```

Comment: have tried something close to the above, how do i iterate if i had say thousands of dd values? And what about writing each result in a separate txt file?

Comment: I'm in the process of writing the solution for the 3 values. To generalize it you need something that makes it possible to know the `.dd -> filename` association.

Comment: no, have not figured out how to do the association (.dd -> filename association), but any solution that goes a bit closer mine would be highly appreciated

Comment: How do you yourself know that `d5f` is `departmentone` ? I doubt you have retained thousands of codes by head, so it must be documented in some file, from which you could hopefully extract the whole association

Comment: yes, it is in a tab separated file. what i meant is i have not found a way to implement this association with jq code

Comment: Nice, just remove the `IFS=:` from the above `while/read` loop and it should work just fine

Comment: It would be possible to handle this directly from `jq`, and it would probably be an execution speed boost (just because you wouldn't need to invoke `jq` thousands of time), but you should then aim to convert your TSV file to a json file as a first step, handling TSV values directly from `jq` would be more troubles than it's worth